# Matching multiple classes with an XPath expression

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

I am trying to automate the Scenario of NSE India https://www.nseindia.com/.

I am trying to capture the Nifty50 increment or decrement value using Xpath as `//nobr/span[@class='red'][1]` when sensex is down and `//nobr/span[@class='green'][1]` when sensex is up. I need to handle this dynamic value in one xpath.

I tried with `//nobr/span[@class='green' OR @class='red'][1]`. This is throwing an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //nobr/span[@class='green' OR @class='red'][1] because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//nobr/span[@class='green' OR @class='red'][1]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

The code:

```
package testcases;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Nifty_Search {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "B:\\Automation\\software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.nseindia.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Normal Market Status :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='status1']")).getText().trim());
    System.out.println("Nifty 50 Today's Price :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='right']//nobr")).getText().trim());
    System.out.println("Nifty 50 Today's Price Change :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nobr/span[@class='green' OR @class='red'][1]")).getText().trim());
    System.out.println("Company_Name :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nobr/span[@class='arrowGreen']")).getText().trim());       
    System.out.println("Nifty 50 Today's Price change Percentage :: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nobr/span[@class='green' OR @class='red'][2]")).getText().trim());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just that the *case of the XPath operators matters*. Change `OR` to `or`:

```
//nobr/span[@class='green' or @class='red'][1]
```

Note that it would probably a bit more reliable to look for this element in the `div` with the `id="niftyDiv"` only since `green` and `red` classes are really broad. And, I would switch to a CSS selector instead for a more concise locator:

```
#niftyDiv nobr > .red,.green
```

Another reason why prefer CSS selector instead of an XPath is that of the `class` attribute handling, it is a *multi-valued attribute*  and is naturally addressed in CSS selectors - XPath has no special handling for multi-valued attributes.